# EXCEL - Using SUMIFS formula with date range, need year to be retrieved from different cell

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I am using a SUMIFS formula in Excel to calculate different expenses throughout the months of the year.  I am trying to build a permanent solution where I only have to update the year in a different cell, and it will carry through the SUMIFS formulas used throughout the page.

Every approach I have taken has voided the formula.  Here is what I have:

'=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,">=1/1/2015",B:B,"<=1/31/2015",E:E,"XYZ")

Comment: The formula as is works on my end.  Are you sure your dates are actual dates and not text in the form of dates?

Comment: The formula works; however, I am trying to use the year 2015 from another cell, so I can roll this over to 2016 just by changing the year in the cell.

Comment: For clarification, I would like to reference the year from a different cell without having to update each formula to 2016.  i.e.

'=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,">=1/1/[CELLA1]",B:B,"<=1/31/[CELLA1]",E:E,"XYZ")

Comment: Aww,  then in place of `">=1/1/2015"` put `">=" & DATE(G1,1,1)` and in place of `"<=1/31/2015"` put `">=" & DATE(G1,1,31)`  Where G1 is the cell that contains the year.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!

Comment: You should accept @SilentRevolution answer.  Click on the green arrow by his answer.  He took the time to put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(A2,12,31),E:E,"XYZ")
```

`A2` in this case is the location of the year.

Note: It would seem @ScottCraner and I had the same solution.